# How to add the option tag inside php table and pass the selected value to mysql db without submit button?

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I have created an escalation system where user uploads .csv file and user can view the uploaded details in web page.

An option tag will be displayed in each row with the below options:

- First level Escalation sent
- Second level  Escalation sent
- Third level   Escalation sent.

I simply want to store the selected item to save in the DB, so the other agent who use the system can see which level escalation has been sent for each complaints.

Here is my code. I am unable to store the option item in DB. Ex: When I select "*First level Escalation sent" it doesn't display to others. Pls help

```html
<table width="100%" border="1" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" style="font-size:10.5px; font-family:verdana;" >
<tr>  
    <td>Name</td>
    <td>SR Number</td>
    <td>Service Impact</td>
    <td>Customer Ref No</td>
    <td>Reported Date and Time</td>
    <td>Issue</td>
    <td>Pending Reason as per TAC</td>
    <td>Expected Time for Resolution</td>
    <td>TAC Agent</td>
    <td>Cx Contact</td>
    <td>Elapsed Time</td>
    <td>Archive</td>
    <td>Send Email</td>
    <td>Comment</td>
</tr>

<?php
while ($ccs=mysqli_fetch_assoc($records)) {
    $A=$ccs['Name'];
    $B=$ccs['SRNumber'];
    $C=$ccs['ServiceImpact'];
    $D=$ccs['CustomerRefNo'];
    $E=$ccs['ReportedDateAndTime'];
    $F=$ccs['Issue'];
    $G=$ccs['PendingReasonAsPerTAC'];
    $H=$ccs['ETR'];
    $I=$ccs['TACAgent'];
    $J=$ccs['Cxcontact'];
  
    echo("   
 <tr class='options'>
        <td>$A</td>
 <td>$B</td>
 <td>$C</td>
 <td>$D</td>
        <td>$E</td>
 <td>$F</td>
 <td>$G</td>
 <td>$H</td>
 <td>$I</td>
 <td>$J</td>
 <td>
     ");
    date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Colombo');
    $the_time = date('H:i');
    $hours = "00";
    $minutes = "00";
    $seconds = "00";
   
    $new_time=$E;
    $datetime1 = new DateTime($the_time); 
    $datetime2 = new DateTime($new_time);
    $interval = $datetime2->diff($datetime1);   
    $hours=$interval->format('%h');
    $minutes= $interval->format('%i');
    $seconds= $interval->format('%s');

    echo $hours." Hours  ".$minutes."  Minutes ".$seconds." Seconds</br></br>";
    echo("
    <td><a href=Escalation_Display.php?delete=$B>Archive</a></td>
    <td><a href=Escalation_Display.php?ID=$B>Email</a> </td>  
    <td>
        <select id='select'>
            <option value='1'>select</option>
            <option value='2'>First level Escalation sent</option>
            <option value='3'>SECOND</option>
            <option>THIRD</option>
            <option>CLOSURE NOT SENT</option>
        </select>
    </td>
</tr>
    ");
}
?>
</table>
```

thanks in advance

[image]

[image]

Comment: Your question is not clear. Can you please clarify the exact problem. Are you asking how to save the selected option to the database without submitting the form (i.e. no page refresh)?

Comment: You want to send **Archive** also

Comment: @browdzone: Well Edited.

Comment: If there is two users (Ex: A & B); if A select " First level escalation sent" option, then the page should display the selected item to B as well. Here when A select " First level escalation sent" option, it doesn't display it to B. It shows default item "Select". So i thought if the selected item get saved in the DB, so it will update frequently & display the last selected item to all. Is my question clear tristan? Please help

Comment: No Nana Partykar, I only want to display the selected option to all. Lets say User A select " First level escalation sent". Then B selects "Second level escalation sent". I want it to get update in DB and display the last selected option "" Second level escalation sent".

Comment: Ok. Ok. I got it. Wait.

Comment: Sure. :) Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Make one column name `Comment` in table from where you are fetching record (`$records`). I tried. I gave you how to do. But, please make changes in if condition in `<select></select>` if required.

```
<?
    .
    .
    while ($ccs=mysqli_fetch_assoc($records)){
        $B=$ccs['SRNUMBER']; I assumed column 'id' (Primary Key and auto-incremented). Change with your column name.
        $escValue=$ccs['Comment']; I assumed column 'escalation_value' as i wrote above.
        .
        .
        .
        ?><td>
            <select id='selectEscalation'>
                <option hidden>Select</option>
                if($escValue != 1) {
                <option value="1."-".$B;">First level Escalation sent</option>
                }
                if($escValue != 2 && $escValue == 1) {
                <option value="2 . "-" . $B;">Second level Escalation sent</option>
                }
                if($escValue != 3 && $escValue==2) {
                <option value="3."-".$B;">Third level Escalation sent</option>
                }
                if($escValue == 3) {
                <option>CLOSURE NOT SENT</option>
                }
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>");
    }
    ?>
</table>

<script>
    $('#selectEscalation').change(function(){
        var EscalationValue=$('#selectEscalation').val();
        $.ajax({url:"Ajax-submitEscalation.php?EscalationValue="+EscalationValue,cache:false,success:function(result){
            alert("Escalation Sent");
        }});
    }); 
</script>
```

**Ajax-submitEscalation.php**

```
<?
// split the contents of $_POST['data'] on a hyphen, returning at most two items
list($data_value, $data_id) = explode("-", $_POST['EscalationValue'], 2);

//escalation_value column name as i wrote above.
$Query="UPDATE TableName SET Comment='$data_value' WHERE SRNUMBER='$data_id'"

?>
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your support. The code works fine. But the selected item from options doesn't get stored in database. I selected "First level escalation". but the default options display on other users' computer. Pls help @Nana

Comment: I have replaced the printscreen. Kindly check above. When I remote login and check, other users it shows default option "Select"

Comment: First Tell Me, Value Getting Stored In Database Table Or Not ? Because, It Should Get Store In Your Table @Sugs

Comment: If It Is Storing. Then, I Can Help You. Not A Problem. I Found Why It Is Showing `Select` To Other Users. But, Before That I Have To Know Whether Value Getting Stored Or Not. Please Tell Me @Sugs

Comment: No :(. Its not getting stored in Database

Comment: `$id=$ccs['id'];` You are passing correct column value here @Sugs?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96869/discussion-between-nana-partykar-and-sugs).